# SQL server temporary connection failure from particular clients

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

We have a client deployment of our software that is showing intermittent SQL server connection failures, and we are struggling to understand them.

Our system consists of a SQL Server DB (2012) and 14 identical engines, each installed on a Windows 2012 VM. Each of these was created from the same template so they should be identical. The engines consist of a Windows service that connects to the DB on startup by reading a single row from a table. If the connection fails they will wait a few seconds and try again, until they get a connection.

In this particular case, the VMs were all rebooted due to a Windows Update. (The SQL server had the update/reboot about 12 hours before). They came online within a few minutes of each other. 12 of the engines started up without any problem. Two of them, however, failed to connect to the DB with:

> "The underlying provider failed on Open."

Those two engines then started to poll, and continued to get this error for many hours. The rest of the engines had started up and were fine. We have a broker service too that was accessing the DB throughout and showed no connection issues.

When the client noticed this issue, they restarted the engine services on the two problem VMs, and the two engines connected to the DB just fine.

We are trying to understand what could have happened here. I guess my main questions are:

1. What could be an explanation of why 12 connections succeed and two fail? There's absolutely no difference as far as we know between the engines. The query itself is very simple.
2. Why did the connection continue to fail for those two engines until the service was restarted? This suggests to me that there is some process-level failed state that is only cleared when restarting the services. I've looked at the code to see if it was reusing the connections. It uses Entity Framework to read the single table row, and we create a fresh DbContext each time. I don't understand how this could go wrong.

We noted that there was a CheckDb operation proceeding on the DB around the time the services were coming up, and we wondered if this could be related to the issue. However, the client says that this runs every night and hasn't caused problems in the past. And it wouldn't explain why the engines didn't come back up again.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: can you paste the entire error

Comment: Unfortunately, I only have the high level description, "The underlying provider failed on Open." That's a flaw with our polling code, that it doesn't log out the full text of the exception.